How can I use low-level operations to add floating points numbers together?
I'm running into an issue in my C++ code.
My goal is to create a function that adds two floating point numbers together, WITHOUT using floating point instructions.
I also need to use as low-level operations as possible, because I need to translate it to assembly language.
So I'm able to get the correct results to values like 1.5 + 2.5, 1.5 + -1.5, and 13.6 + 52.1.
However, when I input something like 1,000,000 + 0.0001, I'm getting 1.4295e+06.
If I add 1,000,000 with 0, I correctly get 1e+06.
So I'm assuming that the issue has to do with imprecision in floating point values.
The code in question:
#include <iostream>

union FloatBits {
    float f;
    uint32_t bits;
};

float add_floats(float a, float b) {
    FloatBits a_bits, b_bits;
    a_bits.f = a; // Initialize the 32 bit value
    b_bits.f = b;
    
    uint32_t a_sign = a_bits.bits & 0x80000000; // Sign 
    a_sign = a_sign >> 31;
    uint32_t a_exponent = a_bits.bits & 0x7f800000; // Exponent
    a_exponent = a_exponent >> 23;
    uint32_t a_mantissa = a_bits.bits & 0x7fffff; // Mantissa

    uint32_t b_sign = b_bits.bits & 0x80000000; // Sign 
    b_sign = b_sign >> 31;
    uint32_t b_exponent = b_bits.bits & 0x7f800000; // Exponent
    b_exponent = b_exponent >> 23;
    uint32_t b_mantissa = b_bits.bits & 0x7fffff; // Mantissa

    std::cout << a_sign << "|" << a_exponent << "|" << a_mantissa << std::endl;
    std::cout << b_sign << "|" << b_exponent << "|" << b_mantissa << std::endl;

    if (a == 0 && b == 0) { 
        return 0.0;
    } else if (a == 0) {
        return b;
    } else if (b == 0) {
        return a;
    }

    // Add the implicit 1's
    a_mantissa |= 0x00800000;
    b_mantissa |= 0x00800000;

    // Normalize
    if (a_exponent < b_exponent) {
        a_mantissa = a_mantissa >> (b_exponent - a_exponent);
        a_exponent = b_exponent;
    } else if (b_exponent < a_exponent) {
        b_mantissa = b_mantissa >> (a_exponent - b_exponent);
        b_exponent = a_exponent;
    } // Else the exponents are equal.  

    uint32_t sign;
    uint32_t exponent = a_exponent; // the exponents are the same due to normalization
    uint32_t mantissa;
    // Add the mantissas
    if (a_sign == b_sign) {
        sign = a_sign;
        mantissa = a_mantissa + b_mantissa;
    } else {
        if (a_mantissa > b_mantissa) {
            sign = a_sign;
            mantissa = a_mantissa - b_mantissa;
        } else if (b_mantissa > a_mantissa){
            sign = b_sign;
            mantissa = b_mantissa - a_mantissa;
        } else if (a_mantissa == b_mantissa) {
            sign = 0;
            exponent = 0;
            mantissa = 0;
        }
    }

    // Handle mantissa overflow
    if (mantissa >= 0x01000000) {
        mantissa >>= 1;
        exponent++;
    }
    std::cout << "-------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << sign << "|" << exponent << "|" << mantissa << std::endl;

    FloatBits result;
    result.bits = (sign << 31) | (exponent << 23) | (mantissa & 0x007fffff);
    // std::cout << a << " + " << b << " = " << result.f << std::endl; 
    return result.f;
}

int main() {
    float num1, num2;
    std::cout << "Enter two numbers: ";
    std::cin >> num1 >> num2;
    float test = add_floats(num1, num2);
    std::cout << test;
    return 0;
}

Aside from efficiency, I think my code works for most numbers, except for that exception mentioned earlier.
I made sure I was normalizing the exponents correctly, but I'm not sure about how I handle mantissa overflow.
I need your thoughts.
Edit: OK I just realized I broke my own rules (no FP instructions) Will fix that thank you.
Update: I just went straight to asm. I think asm is much easier than this

By the C++ standard, type punning through a union is undefined behavior.  (C and C++ differ here, because in C it is well-defined behavior.)  Your compiler may have a platform specific compiler extension that makes in a compiler vendor well-defined behavior.  If you want a C++ solution, consider using std::bits or std::memcpy to shuffle the raw bytes around.

I normally compile and run by non-release builds with -fsanitize=undefined,null,address,bounds,bool,enum, which showed the runtime error of runtime error: shift exponent 33 is too large for 32-bit type 'uint32_t' (aka 'unsigned int').  You should vet your shift amounts to make sure they are within range (less than the bit-size of an int, which on my platform is <32).

Note: "WITHOUT using floating point instructions" --> if (a == 0 && b == 0) { is doing 2 float compares.

You say that your code, when adding 1,000,000 + 0.0001 gives a result something like 1.4295e+06.     That won't occur just because of limitations related to floating point precision.     That's a sign of a bug in your program (e.g. if it incorrectly parses input "1000000" and produces a numeric value wildly different from 1000000).   One source of such a bug may be the presence of undefined behaviour due to type punning

@peter ok thank you I will look more carefully at what I have.

@chux Yeah that is very bad of me. Will fix that.


Unprotected shift: a_mantissa >> (b_exponent - a_exponent); risks shifting 32 or more --> undefined behavior (UB).  Certainly OP's current woe.

Code does a floating point compare against 0.0 (a == 0) even though no FP operations are desired.

Code fails to handle subnormals, infinity, NAN.

Code does not round.  Usually round to nearest - ties to even is preferred.



I'd say there is quite a bit more for OP to do, so here's something to get started in a more organized approach.
Use helper functions to convert to/from float
typedef struct {
  uint32_t significant;
  int expo;
  bool nan, inf, sign;
} float_parts;

static float_parts float_to_parts(float x) {
  int32_t bits;
  memcpy(&bits, &x, sizeof bits);
  float_parts y = {.sign = bits < 0, .significant = bits & 0x7FFFFFu, //
      .expo = (bits & 0x7F800000) >> 23};

  if (y.expo >= 0xFFF) {
    if (y.significant > 0) {
      y.nan = true;
    } else {
      y.inf = true;
    }
  } else {
    if (y.expo > 0) {
      y.significant |= 0x800000;
    }
    y.expo -= 127; // bias
  }
  return y;
}

Some pseudo code for OP to see the extant of what is needed.
float add(float af, float bf) {
  a = float_to_parts(af);
  b = float_to_parts(bf);
  
  // Handle Infinity, NAN
  TBD_code()

  if (a.sign != b.sign) {
    return sub(af, -bf);
  }

  if (b < a) {
    swap(a,b);
  }

  if (isZero(b)) {
    return a;
  }

  // Hmmm, On reflection, I'd do the below in float_to_parts()
  adjust a.significant, a.expo if a.significant is small.
  adjust b.significant, b.expo if b.significant is small.

  shift = a.expo - b.epxo;
  if (shift > large) {  // large is maybe 31
    shift = large; 
  }

  // Shift b.significant
  bool round = Last bit shifted out >= BASE/2
  bool sticky = True if any other bits shifted out are non-zero.
  b.significant >>= shift;

  // Add
  a.significant += b.significant
  
  // Carry out?
  if (a.significant > signicant_max) {
    update sticky
    update round
    a.significant >>= 1
    a.expo++
  }

  // Round to closest - ties to even
  if (round && (sticky || (a.significant & 1))) {
    a.significant++
    if (a.significant > significant_max) {
      a.significant >>= 1
      a.expo++
    }
  }

  // Detect overflow
  if (a.significant > significant_max) {
    a.inf = true;
  }

  return float_from_parts(a);
}

